# Download PDF received from API using Express

Tags: node.js, express, pdf

I'm currently calling an API that returns a pdf
This is my code.

```
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'myurl',
    headers: {
    accept: 'application/pdf',
    encoding: null,
    authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    },
  }

Then i make the request
try{
    var file = await request(options,(error,response,body) => {
      if(error) throw new Error(error)
    })
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
  }
console.log(file)
```

The console.log prints what i assume is the pdf encoded

```
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 15130
>>
stream
-qO�▲$�֤���� K�;�Cn��V��!R�♂�PA�D
// And prints a lot more of these characters
```

However when i try to download it as pdf, it downloads an empty pdf. I was doing this:

```
    fs.writeFileSync("./report/report.pdf",file);
res.download("./report/report.pdf",'report.pdf')
```

If someone could help me,
Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?